# How to proper bundle website assets using webpack

Tags: webpack

I have a static website that has as assets .js, .css, .svg and .pngs files.

I am trying to use webpack to bundle then all together but so far no success.

Here is what I have so far. Any thoughts? If you know of an online resource, please post the link.

My goal is to have the minimum amount of HTTP requests and have everything minified.

```
    'use strict';
    const webpack = require('webpack'),
          path =  require('path'),
          glob = require('glob');
    let config = {
      entry: {
        'myPages': glob.sync('./js/**/*.js'),
        // 'vendor':[
        //   'jquery'
        // ],
      },
      module: {
        loaders: [
           // CSS: scss, css
           {
             test: /\.s?css$/,
             loaders: ['style', 'css', 'sass', 'postcss-loader']
           },
           // SVGs: svg, svg?something
           {
             test: /\.svg(\?.*$|$)/,
             loader: 'file-loader?name=/img/[name].[ext]'
           },
           // Images: png, gif, jpg, jpeg
           {
             test: /\.(png|gif|jpe?g)$/,
             loader: 'file?name=/img/[name].[ext]'
           },
           // HTML: htm, html
           {
             test: /\.html?$/,
             loader: "file?name=[name].[ext]"
           },
           // Font files: eot, ttf, woff, woff2
           {
             test: /\.(eot|ttf|woff2?)(\?.*$|$)/,
             loader: 'file?name=/fonts/[name].[ext]'
           }
        ]
      },
      output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle--[name].js'
      },
    };
    module.exports = config;
```

Comment: You are using the file-loader to load images, and fonts. This will always leave those assets as discrete files, and simply give you a resolved path to those assets. If you really want everything bundled you should consider using the url-loader which will convert all images and files into base64 strings, or raw-loader which will just return you the plain text of the file.

Comment: If you have a lot of entry files you will probably want to use the CommonsChunkPlugin to split out dependencies that all your entries share. This way users who go from one page to another won't have to redownload all your vendor code.

Answer (score 0):

When `entry` is an array Webpack doesn't create a separate bundle for each element. Instead it's like it concats them all together into one entry point. If you want separate bundles you have to pass an object where the keys are the names of the bundles. Since glob.sync returns an array you could reduce that to an object like so

```
const entries = glob.sync('./js/**/*.js')
    .reduce(function(entries, filepath) {
        return entries[path.parse(filepath).name] = filepath;
    }, {});
```

You'll also want to add `[name]` to your `output.filename`

```
output: {
        // Make sure to use [name] or [id] in output.filename
        //  when using multiple entry points
        filename: "[name].bundle.js",
        chunkFilename: "[id].bundle.js"
    }
```

You may have to do something more creative with the names so that they are unique, but you get the idea.